# Has anybody used Plugins(Interceptors) for Magento 1 from SafeMage Team?

Tags: magento-1.9, plugin, interceptor

everybody!
Could anybody tell me if he use  Plugins(Interceptors) from this team?
http://www.safemage.com/function-plugins-for-magento-1.html

It seems it is similar to the same functionality of Magento 2

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE! Open questions and discussions are not a good fit for the StackExchange Q&A format - you'll get better
results at the Magento forums (http://community.magento.com) or
Reddit (http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento)

Comment: I used Magento2 Interceptors but have never used Magento 1. Can anybody advice??